# MongoDB - How to access a newly created array field created with $lookup and aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assuming I have two collections:

courses:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Geometry",
    teacher_id: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "English",
    teacher_id: 2
  }
]
```

teachers:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Adams"
  },
  {
     _id: 2,
     firstName: "Mary",
     lastName: "Jane"
  }
]
```

Now I perform an aggregation on the two collections to create something similar to a join in SQL:

```
db.collection("courses").aggregate([
      {
        $lookup:{
              from: "teachers",
              localField: "teacher_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "teacher_info"
          }
      },
      {
        $match:{
          //I want to perform a match or filter here on the teacher_info
        }
      }
]);
```

The `$lookup` and aggregation will return a list of documents that have a new teacher_info array field.

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Geometry",
    teacher_id: 1,
    teacher_info: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Adams"
      },
   ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "English",
    teacher_id: 1,
    teacher_info: [
      {
         _id: 2,
         firstName: "Mary",
         lastName: "Jane"
      },
   ]
  }
]
```

I need to perform a match operation in the newly created teacher_info array field. For example, only keep the teacher that has the first name "John". How can I do so? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in your `$match` stage.

```
{
  $match: {
    "teacher_info.firstName": "John"
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ydvhiyLe8EL)

Comment: Thank you sir. But, why is teacher_info.firstName in quotation?

Comment: Because the dot symbol cannot be allowed as the JSON property key **without quotes**. Hence, to avoid get the error due to it, you need to wrap the whole `teacher_info.firstName` in quotes.

Comment: wait what? dot is not a json property name

Comment: Think this [article](https://restfulapi.net/valid-json-key-names/) may help you.

Comment: So, a JSON key must be wrapped in double quotes. However, this isn't JSON. This is MongoDB, and how come the field names aren't wrapped in quotes when you view the data?

Comment: I think it's just a MongoDB syntax that you need double quote to access its children. Another thing I notice teacher_info is an array, but "teacher_info.firstName" returns a field

Comment: [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248768/discussion-between-rongeegee-and-yong-shun).

Comment: let's say the size of the course document is M, the size of the teacher document is N
what do you think the time complexity of this aggregation be?
is it O(n*m) since the loop through the course collection, and loop through the teacher collection like a double for loop?